# Why can't I call a method on the Object type with a variable of type "any"?

Tags: typescript

What I mean by this is: suppose I extend the Object class like so:

```
interface Object
{
    doSomething();
}

Object.prototype.doSomething = function ()
{
  //do something here
};
```

If I have a variable of type `Object`, I can call:

```
var x: Object = ...;
x.doSomething();
```

and I get Intellisense and compile time type checking.

But if I do this:

```
var x: any = ...;
x.doSomething();
```

I get no help from the compiler.

But I don't understand this, since ALL variables inherit from `Object`, shouldn't the compiler know that anything `Object` can do, `any` should also be able to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the "should" part of your question. When we write `any` we are saying that we don't know anything about the type of the value in question so it makes sense that the intelisense also doesn't assume anything. If our intent is to call methods from Object.prototype it will be clearer if we use `Object` instead of `any` in the type declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> I get no help from the compiler.

The compiler is **hands off** on anything with type `any`. After all, it might not even be something that extends from `Object`.

Comment: Can you give an example of something that doesn't extend Object and that you can't call methods from Object.prototype?

Answer (score 0):

Some things in Javascript, such as `null` and `undefined` are not objects so I guess it makes sense that `any` would not imply `Object` from an intelisense point of view. That said, Typescript has a relaxed typing system that considers `Null` and `Undefined` as [subtypes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11) of `Object` so I guess they *could* have made the Object.prototype stuff show up for things with type `any` if they wanted to.